# Django self-referential relationship?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to create model Page, page should be able to have "child pages" too.

My model code below keeps [crashing Python](http://pastie.org/private/butthk1aaeb3pmh7mmag1g) on my Mac (python 2.6.1) and Ubuntu 10.04 (python 2.6.5):

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin

class Page(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField(blank=True)
    children = models.ManyToManyField("self", blank=True)
    published = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, auto_now_add=True)

    def html(self):
        html = "<li>"
        html += self.title

        children = self.children.all()
        if len(children) > 0:

            for page in children:
                html += page.html()

        html += "</li>"
        return html

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title


class PageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title',)}


admin.site.register(Page, PageAdmin)
```

What am I doing wrong? Or does this kinda HTML-rendering belong to views?

Thanks.

Comment: The number of `PyEval_EvalFrameEx` calls in the stack trace could have led to a stack overflow. Looks much like a Python bug, because normally Python would break recursion at some point with `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`.

Comment: A little comment on your model: a many-to-many relation is probably the wrong representation. In a tree, a node (or in your code, a page) does only have zero or one parent. A foreign key `parent` would be the better representation.

Comment: @piquadrat Thanks for noticing. I blame sleepiness.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest you use `django-mptt` which offers easier to use method of recursively spitting the structure out.

You have to register mptt with the model [first](https://django-mptt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html), though.

Here is my code using it: [Including foreign key count in django mptt full tree listing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224837/including-foreign-key-count-in-django-mptt-full-tree-listing)

Comment: Works perfectly & easy to use. Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

In terms of the model itself you're just thinking of this in the wrong direction. Instead of

```
children = models.ManyToManyField("self", blank=True)
```

use

```
parent = models.ForeignKey("self", blank=True, related_name="children")
```

This will let you access the children directly from a page record but should be a more straightforward representation in the database.

HTML rendering should generally happen in views, not in the model. Use mptt as meder suggests.