# I have a OneToOne relationship between two objects of the same class in a Django app. Is it possible to enforce the uniqueness of this relationship?

Tags: python, django, database, database-design, django-models

I have the following in my app:

```
class University(models.Model):
    ...
    sister_university = models.OneToOneField('self', related_name = 
                        'university_sister_university', 
                        blank=True, null=True, 
                        on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

I only want a university to be related to one other university in both directions of that relationship.

For example, in the database, if I select university A as the sister_university of university B, I only want to be allowed to select university B as the sister_university under university A also. However, as it is, that second relationship is not enforced.

For example: Right now, under the Django Admin site, if I first select university A as the sister university of university B, I am still able to select any other university as the sister university of the university A object. I’m not constrained to only selecting university B.

Is it possible to enforce that uniqueness at the database level? Is there a better way of accomplishing what I’m trying to do?

Comment: I haven't tried this myself, so I don't have a detailed answer, but you might check out [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38261573/2715819).

Comment: I can confirm that you can do this; but the constraint is not enforced; not even if you set `unique_together`. I guess this is first and foremost a SQL question; before being a django question.

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/325284/specifying-a-bi-directional-unique-constraint-on-a-join-table-in-postgres

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think that what you need is to make this relationship **symmetric**.

You can accomplish this by overriding the `save()` method of the `University` model:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(University, self).save()
    if self.sister_university:
        self.sister_university.sister_university = self
```

Comment: @BearBrown, Does that mean that sometimes you want `UniversityA` to have `UniversityB` as a `sister_university` while `UniversityB` having a `null` as a `sister_university` ?

Comment: @BearBrown, Oh okay.. As far as I understand he needs the symmetry to always happens. What do you think?

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work for me in admin , and in view I had to save both instances, any suggestions please?

Answer (score 2):

I never did this kind of things, but I think that you can make this process through this way :

#### Method : unique_together()

You can use `Options.unique_together` and set your university_A and university_B as a unique pair.

```
unique_together = ("university_A", "university_B")
```

In your models.py file, you should have something like this (with maybe some issues, but the idea is there) :

```
class University(models.Model):
    ...
    university = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sister_university = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    class Meta:
        unique_together     = (('university','sister_university'),)
```

You should find precious details there : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/options/

I never tried this command, but it seems to solve your issue according to your context.

Comment: three university, `a, b, c` if `a` is sister `b` then `c` can't be sister `a`, i don't think the `unique_together` help.

Comment: @BearBrown Yes, but if I well-understood the issue, there is just university A and B no ? He just wants to pairing universities ?

Comment: no two side unique. other way i didn't create the bounty.

Comment: Hum, I think that `unique_together` or `through model` with signals are the only solutions to solve his issue.